# Как правильно производить сериализацию объекта

Tags: c#, сериализация

Доброго времени суток!

Как правильно производить сериализации объектов? Предполагается реализовать красиво метод сохранения настроек приложения в xml формат. Сейчас сделано топорно через `xmlwriter` переписывается файл при закрытии приложения.

Видел в примерах кода атрибуты `serizable` и прочее, наверняка что-то полезное. Расскажите, как правильно организовать в коде логику, где почитать умные слова на эту тему?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Авторы говорят так: [Примеры XML-сериализации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/58a18dwa.aspx)

> XML-сериализация может иметь несколько форм, от простой до сложной. Например, можно сериализовать класс, который состоит всего лишь из открытых полей и свойств, как показано в разделе Введение в XML-сериализацию. В следующих примерах кода представлены различные сложные сценарии, включая способы использования XML-сериализации для создания потока XML, соответствующего определенному документу схемы XML (XSD).